# NSLayoutContraints: How to position a bottom view below the higher of two labels?

Tags: ios, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint, ios-autolayout

I am working on an iOS 11+ app and would like to create a view like in this picture:

[image: View]

The two labels are positioned to work as columns of different height depending on the label content. The content of both labels is variable due to custom text entered by the user. Thus I cannot be sure which of the the two labels is higher at runtime and there is also no limit to the height.

**How can I position the `BottomView` to have a margin 20px to the higher of the two columns / labels?**

Both labels should only use the min. height necessary to show all their text. Thus giving both labels an equal height is no solution.

I tried to use vertical spacing **greater than** 20px to both labels but this leads (of course) to an `Inequality Constraint Ambiguity`.

**Is it possible to solve this simple task with Autolayout only or do I have to check / set the sizes and margins manually in code?**

Comment: It is bit strange to put a question on hold because it is unclear what was asked **after** an answer was accepted, isn't it? The question cannot be that unclear if someone posts an answer which exactly solves the described problem just a few minutes after the question was asked, can it? The only thing which might be missing, is that the two colums should keep their individual heights and should be top aligned. What else am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]
You can add labels to stackView

Comment: Actually the stack view is irrelevant. Any self sizing superview would do here. A plain UIView would accomplish the same thing.

Comment: @matt How would you configure / position a plain `UIView` to match the height of the bigger of the two lables?

Comment: @matt The stack view obviously has a lot more build in options / possibilities to arrange its subviews than a plain `UIView`. Using the stack view I can simply set the `allignment = top` property to get the desired result. Could you describe in more detail how this can be done using a `UIView` and constraints only? How would you make sure, that the `UIView` gets its height from the bigger of the two labels (without knowing which label this is) while the smaller label only uses the min. heights it needs?

Comment: @AndreiHerford Are you really interested in the details and you'd like to learn, or are you just yanking my chain? If you're really interested, how would you like it explained? A comment is too short and unstructured. Would like me to give the actual answer as an answer, or would a downloadable example do?

Comment: @matt I'm sorry if I gave the impression that I didn't mean the question seriously. Of course I don't want to waste your time, but I really want to understand how the problem can be solved with a simple UIView (otherwise the question would also be a waste of time for me). I don't know if I am missing the forest through the trees, but I really don't see how that can be done with a UIView. I think adding an answer here would be the easiest solution but if a downloadable example is easier for you this is fine as well of course.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is to assign equal height constraint to both label. By doing this height of label will always be equal to large label (Label with more content).

You can do this by selecting both labels and adding equal height constraint as mentioned in screen short.

[image]

Result would be some think like below

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the good answer! However, this does not solve the problem since the text in both labels should be top aligned.

Answer (score 1):

The answer given as https://stackoverflow.com/a/57571805/341994 does work, but it is not very educational. "Use a stack view." Yes, but what is a stack view? It is a view that makes constraints for you. It is not magic. What the stack view does, you can do. An ordinary view surrounding the two labels and sizing itself to the longer of them would do fine. The stack view, as a stack view, is not doing anything special here. You can build the same thing just using constraints yourself.

(Actually, the surrounding view is not really needed either, but it probably makes things a bit more encapsulated, so let's go with that.)

Here's a version of your project running on my machine:

[image]

And with the other label made longer:

[image]

So how is that done? It's just ordinary constraints. Here's the storyboard:

[image]

Both labels have a greater-than-or-equal constraint (which happens to have a constant of 20) from their bottom to the bottom of the superview. All their other constraints are obvious and I won't describe them here.

Okay, but that is not quite enough. There remains an ambiguity, and Xcode will tell you so. Inequalities need to be resolved somehow. We need something on the far side of the inequality to aim at. The solution is one more constraint: the superview itself has a height constraint of 1 *with a priority of 749*. That is a low enough priority to permit the compression resistance of the labels to operate.

So the labels get their full height, and the superview tries to collapse as short as possible to 1, but it is prevented by the two inequalities: its bottom must be more than 20 points below the bottom of both labels. And so we get the desired result: the bottom of the superview ends up *exactly* 20 points below the bottom of the *longest* label.

Comment: And see https://github.com/mattneub/LongerLabel for a downloadable demonstration project you can play with.

Comment: Thank you very much for the excellent answer! Using the height = 1 constraint to give AutoLayout the information to solve the ambigutiy is the trick I was missing!